# How to split a panel data record in R based on a threshold value for a variable?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, panel-data

I have data for hospitalisations that records date of admission and the number of days spent in the hospital:

```
ID    date        ndays
1     2005-06-01   15
2     2005-06-15   60
3     2005-12-25   20
4     2005-01-01   400
4     2006-06-04   15
```

I would like to create a dataset of days spend at the hospital per year, and therefore I need to deal with cases like ID 3, whose stay at the hospital goes over the end of the year, and ID 4, whose stay at the hospital is longer than one year. There is also the problem that some people do have a record on next year, and I would like to add the `surplus' days to those when this happens.

So far I have come up with this solution:

```
library(lubridate)
ndays_new <- ifelse((as.Date(paste(year(data$date),"12-31",sep="-")),
                                   format="%Y-%m-%d") - data$date) < data$ndays,
                    (as.Date(paste(year(data$date),"12-31",sep="-")),
                                   format="%Y-%m-%d") - data$date) ,
                    data$ndays)
```

However, I can't think of a way to get those `surplus' days that go over the end of the year and assign them to a new record starting on the next year. Can any one point me to a good solution? I use dplyr, so solutions with that package would be specially welcome, but I'm willing to try any other tool if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution isn't compact. But, I tried to employ `dplyr` and did the following. I initially changed column names for my own understanding. I calculated another date (i.e., date.2) by adding `ndays` to `date.1`. If the years of `date.1` and `date.2` match, that means you do not have to consider the following year. If the years do not match, you need to consider the following year. `ndays.2` is basically ndays for the following year. Then, I reshaped the data using `do`. After filtering unnecessary rows with NAs, I changed `date` to `year` and aggregated the data by `ID` and `year`.

```
rename(mydf, date.1 = date, ndays.1 = ndays) %>%
mutate(date.1 = as.POSIXct(date.1, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
       date.2 = date.1 + (60 * 60 * 24) * ndays.1,
       ndays.2 = ifelse(as.character(format(date.1, "%Y")) == as.character(format(date.2, "%Y")), NA,
                        date.2 - as.POSIXct(paste0(as.character(format(date.2, "%Y")),"-01-01"), format = "%Y-%m-%d")),
       ndays.1 = ifelse(ndays.2 %in% NA, ndays.1, ndays.1 - ndays.2)) %>%
do(data.frame(ID = .$ID, date = c(.$date.1, .$date.2), ndays = c(.$ndays.1, .$ndays.2))) %>%
filter(complete.cases(ndays)) %>%
mutate(date = as.numeric(format(date, "%Y"))) %>%
rename(year = date) %>%
group_by(ID, year) %>%
summarise(ndays = sum(ndays))

#  ID year ndays
#1  1 2005    15
#2  2 2005    60
#3  3 2005     7
#4  3 2006    13
#5  4 2005   365
#6  4 2006    50
```